# row naming issue with bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have

```
"Can not set java.util.List field com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow.f to java.lang.String"
```

when naming row as "f".

What steps will reproduce the problem?

```
TableRow row = new TableRow();
row.set("f", 7.7);
TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows rows = new TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows();
rows.setInsertId(timestamp);
rows.setJson(row);
List  rowList = new ArrayList();
rowList.add(rows);
TableDataInsertAllRequest content =  new TableDataInsertAllRequest().setRows(rowList);
TableDataInsertAllResponse response = bigquery.tabledata().insertAll(
        projectId, datasetId, tableId, content).execute();
```

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?

Renaming column to smth. like f1 works OK.

Gradle dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':shared')
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-servlet:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-bigquery:v2-rev171-1.19.0'
    compile 'redis.clients:jedis:2.4.2'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.4'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.4'
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.16'
    compile 'org.json:json:20090211'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.10.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.10.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.10.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-jetty-servlet:2.10.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.10.1'
    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:0.9.1'
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    compile 'redis.clients:jedis:2.4.2'
    compile 'com.github.fge:json-schema-validator:2.2.5'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.2.1.v20140609'
    compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.12.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-email:1.3.3'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'

}
```

Comment: that actually works with the BigQuery UI.... so maybe create your table with the UI first and then use your code to upload data to it?

Comment: does the same code work when you replace "f" by any other string?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa it worked for me when i used "f1" instead of "f".

Comment: Actually after debugging I have found that class com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow has private property java.util.List<TableCell> f which as far as I understand prevents  from creating row with name f and throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.List field com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow.f to java.lang.String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a TableRow can have multiple fields in it, I usually see the following construction:

```
TableDataInsertAllResponse response = bigquery.tabledata()
    .insertAll(projectId, datasetId, tableId, new TableDataInsertAllRequest()
        .setRows(ImmutableList.of(new TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows()
            .setInsertId(insertId)
            .setJson(new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object>()
                .put("f", 7.7)
                .build())))).execute();
```

Might this work for you?

Note that I include an insertId in that example, since you will want to use it for row-level de-duplication if/when you add retry logic. Feel free to drop it for now if it's not required for your use case.